# PHP Codeigniter - Corrupted image file when using force download for generated qr code

Tags: php, codeigniter, force-download

ive been using several codes i found on stackoverflow but it doesn't seems to solve my problem. I want the generated qr code to be force download to user's desktop instead of specified path. Ive tried ob_clean() and everything. This is the code when it is downloaded to specified path.

```
        public function event()
       {       
        $data['img_url']="";
        if($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == "generate_qrcode")
         {
            $this->load->library('ciqrcode');
            $qr_image=rand().'.png';
            $params['data'] = $this->input->post('qr_text');
            $params['level'] = 'H';
            $params['size'] = 8;
            $params['savename'] =FCPATH."/uploads/".$qr_image;

            if($this->ciqrcode->generate($params))
           {
            $data['img_url']=$qr_image; 
           }
         } 
          $this->load->view('event',$data);
       }
```

and this is the code when i try to force download.

```
       public function event()
     {
      $data['img_url']="";
      if($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == "generate_qrcode")
    {
        $this->load->library('ciqrcode');
        $this->load->helper('download');
        $qr_image=rand().'.png';
        $params['data'] = $this->input->post('qr_text');
        $params['level'] = 'H';
        $params['size'] = 8;
        //$params['savename'] =FCPATH."/uploads/".$qr_image;
        force_download($qr_image, $params);
        if($this->ciqrcode->generate($params))
        {
            $data['img_url']=$qr_image; 
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('event',$data);
}
```

The qr code is downloaded to download files, but when i try to open it, it is said that the file is corrupted. I've tried to see the error on notepad. And this is what it say.

```
A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Array to string conversion</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/download_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 146</p>

<p>Backtrace:</p>
<p style="margin-left:10px">
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\MySystem\application\controllers\admincontrol.php<br />
Line: 244<br />
Function: force_download
```

Can anyone help me on solving this. Thank you.

Comment: What is line 146 of `helpers/download_helper.php`? Apparently, you're sending an array to a function that expects a string.

Comment: line 146 was just this --> if ($data !== NULL) {exit($data);} 
is there any way to change the expected strings?

Comment: If `$data` is an array at that point, that's where your problem is. You could `exit(print_r($data, true));` for example

Comment: hi, you need first save qr_image on server and then download it, if not save on server you only download from cache image and it is not posible for generate a download real file